# Can't make the simplest scaffolding example work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm completely new to Bootstrap, and having a bad start, since I can't even make the simplest example work (!). I have used this [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crh8eLErG1Q&list=PLKlA1QwYBcmcEUUBSmkl8_kgwn-_zuy-W) and this [scaffolding documention page](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html) to write the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
  <style>
    .row { background-color: red; }
    .span3, .span9 { background-color: blue; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='span3'> span3 </div>
      <div class='span9'> span9 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>
  <script src='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously, I want just one row, with one div spanning 3 columns (out of 12) and another div spanning 9 columns. Obviously on the same row. But this is what it looks like in both Firefox and Chrome:

[image]

### Is the Bootstrap javascript loaded correctly?

It makes no difference (not as much as a pixel), if I remove the script element pointing to bootstrap.min.js. Is that supposed to be so?

### Perhaps all the CSS- and JS-warning in Firefox Web Developer Console?

I get lots of CSS-warnings, like:

```
[18:38:44.443] Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css:7
```

And one JS-warning:

```
[18:38:44.629] Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. @ http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js:5375
```

Could that explain something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using syntax for Bootstrap 2 while including Bootstrap 3 file.

The syntax for the same code in Bootstrap 3, would be:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-9">.col-md-9</div>
</div>
```

You can check out the documentation here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/